# Simulators/ Emulators for Cordova Mobile App

Tags: cordova, hybrid-mobile-app, taco

Are there any free/opensource simulators/emulators to test Cordova Hybrid Mobile Application on IOS, Windows Phone, Android.

I know about Ripple emulator, but I need more reliable emulators for all 3 (iOS, Android and Windows Phone).

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need platform independence for inspection, then use weinre:

https://people.apache.org/~pmuellr/weinre-docs/latest/

The only simulator for iOS, that I know is the one from Xcode.

For Android you should try Genymotion:

https://www.genymotion.com/

**And one important tip:**

Before you release your software, test it on real devices. There are huge differences between simulators and real devices. Try to get same slow devices and try to get very small and very large devices.